# Xaml Pass Binding as argument, Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, arguments, parameter-passing

Is there a way to pass a binding or similar as an argument to a non-default constructor in xaml?

like:

```
<MyClass>
    <x:Arguments>
       <x:Boolean>true</x:Boolean>
       <x:Boolean>Binding="{Binding bindingName}"</x:Boolean>
       <x:Double>90</x:Double>
    </x:Arguments>                   
</MyClass>
```

Comment: Make it a `BindableProperty`, binding happens after object construction.

Comment: I would rather just set it up once in the constructor.

Comment: @Oliver Have you found a solution for this?